# Tiny font on Fedora 16

Tags: fedora, fonts, size

I'm finding that several programs have tiny font with Fedora 16. Google Chrome, for example, has miniscule font in the tabs. MATLAB has tiny font in the menus (File, Edit, etc.)

I have the "larger font" accessibility option enables, but it doesn't affect these programs. On Windows, "larger font" does improve the font sizes of these programs.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNOME 3 on fedora core 16, try this.

```
# yum install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Either run it via terminal by typing `gnome-tweak-tool` or search in the menu under “advanced setting”. There you can change the default font settings to whatever you like.

Comment: I installed the tool, but it doesn't do what I need it to. I need 10 reputation to upload an image for illustration purposes--a little help?

Comment: type this in address bar of chrome, "chrome://settings/advanced" and then choose "customize fonts" to your need. A somewhat similar procedure could also work for matlab.